# Make specific column editable based on radio button change in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the datatables. The requirement is  to make certain columns of datatables editable once the user check/click on corresponding radio buttons. For eg: if user clicks on DEA, the corresponding DEA coulmn in both the tables should be editable and so forth as shown in the screenshot. The edited data also needs to be saved in DB.

Client side code:

```
 var $bTable = $('#tblBadFormat').dataTable({
                "sDom": "<'row'<'col-sm-12'<'pull-right'f><'pull-left'l>r<'clearfix'>>>t<'row'<'col-sm-12'<'pull-left'i><'pull-right'p><'clearfix'>>>",
                "bFilter": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bServerSide": true,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("GetBadFormatData")',
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "sName": "ID", "bVisible": false, "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "DEA", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "Product", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "NDC", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "Sales", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "Fees", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "Quantity", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "Contract", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "Fee", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "HIN", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "CustomerName", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "CustomerAddress", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "City", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "State", "bSortable": false }
                ],

                "fnPreDrawCallback": function () {
                    centerThis('Processing');
                    $("#Processing").css("display", "block");
                },

                "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
                    if (oSettings._iDisplayLength < oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay()) {
                        $('.dataTables_paginate').css("display", "block");
                    }
                    else {
                        $('.dataTables_paginate').css("display", "none");
                    }
                    $('#tblBadFormat tbody tr td').each(function () {
                        this.setAttribute('title', "Click to see contracts.");
                    });
                },
                "fnInitComplete": function () {
                    this.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
                    centerThis('Processing');
                    $("#Processing").css("display", "none");
                }
            });

            var $nTable = $('#tblNotInBad').dataTable({
                "sDom": "<'row'<'col-sm-12'<'pull-right'f><'pull-left'l>r<'clearfix'>>>t<'row'<'col-sm-12'<'pull-left'i><'pull-right'p><'clearfix'>>>",
                "bFilter": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bServerSide": true,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("GetNotInBadFormatData")',
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "sName": "ID", "bVisible": false, "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "2%" },
                    { "sName": "DEA", "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "2%" },
                    { "sName": "Product", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "NDC", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "Sales", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "Fees", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "Quantity", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "Contract", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "Fee", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "HIN", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "CustomerName", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "CustomerAddress", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "City", "bSortable": false },
                    { "sName": "State", "bSortable": false }
                ],

                "fnPreDrawCallback": function () {
                    centerThis('Processing');
                    $("#Processing").css("display", "block");
                },

                "fnDrawCallback": function (nSettings) {
                    if (nSettings._iDisplayLength < nSettings.fnRecordsDisplay()) {
                        $('.dataTables_paginate').css("display", "block");
                    }
                    else {
                        $('.dataTables_paginate').css("display", "none");
                    }
                    $('#tblNotInBad tbody tr td').each(function () {
                        this.setAttribute('title', "Click to see contracts.");
                    });
                },
                "fnInitComplete": function () {
                    this.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
                    centerThis('Processing');
                    $("#Processing").css("display", "none");
                }
            });
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="content-box-content">
    <table style="width:100%;font-size:10px;">
        <tr>
            <td >
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="skip" value="Skip Check" />Skip Check
                </label>
            </td>
            <td >
                <label>
                    Check:
                </label>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="filter" value="DEA" id="rdb1" />DEA
                </label>
            </td>

            <td >
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="filter" value="HIN" id="rdb2" />HIN
                </label>
            </td>
            <td >
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="filter" value="NDC" id="rdb3" />NDC
                </label>
            </td>
            <td >
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="filter" value="Contract" id="rdb4" />Contract
                </label>
            </td>
            <td >
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="filter" value="Payment" id="rdb5" />Payment
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">Bad Format:</label>
    <table id="tblBadFormat" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-condensed" style="width:100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">Id</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">DEA</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">Product Name/Description</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">NDC</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">Sales $</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">Fees $</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">Qty/Units</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">Contract #(ID)</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">Fee %</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">HIN</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">Customer Name</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">Customer Address</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">City</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">State</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <label style="font-size:12px;">Not in GPO:</label>
    <table id="tblNotInBad" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-condensed" style="width:100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">Id</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">DEA</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">Product Name/Description</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">NDC</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">Sales $</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">Fees $</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">Qty/Units</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">Contract #(ID)</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">Fee %</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">HIN</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">Customer Name</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">Customer Address</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">City</th>
                <th style="font-size:11px;">State</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Json Response for 1st table:

```
{"sEcho":"1","iTotalRecords":4,"iTotalDisplayRecords":4,"aaData":[["1","22EF581100","Shampoo","0090456890","9.80","4.50","5","2000018590-01","13.33","","JOHNSON","Boston","Houston","Texas"],["2","22EF581100","Toothpaste","0090456890","5.50","3.50","5","2000018590-01","15.66","","Merk","Dallas","Los Angeles","California"],["3","22EF581100","Hair Gel","0090456890","5.66","2.50","5","2000018590-01","14.67","","Sun","Dallas","San Antonio","Texas"],["4","22EF581100","Hair Cream","0090456890","3.33","3.89","5","2000018590-01","12.56","","JOHNSON","Dallas","Dallas","Texas"]]}
```

Json response for 2nd Table:

```
{"sEcho":"1","iTotalRecords":4,"iTotalDisplayRecords":4,"aaData":[["5","22EF581100","Body Deodrant","0090456890"
,"6.50","4.56","3","2000018590-01","11.67","","Olay","San Diego","Lexington","Kentucky"],["6","22EF581100"
,"FaceWash","0090456890","3.50","7.68","6","2000018590-01","10.90","","Facklay","Washington","Kansas
 City","Missouri"],["7","22EF581100","Facial Cream","0090456890","8.90","8.65","8","2000018590-01","45
.67","","Neutrogena","Washington","Buckeye","Arizona"],["8","22EF581100","Perfume","0090456890","2.30"
,"9.78","9","2000018590-01","23.56","","Garnier","Washington","Phoenix","Arizona"]]}
```

Attached is the screenshot of the datatables.[image]

Comment: Please understand this is not ready-to-paste code site. What have you tried? You need to show your efforts first.

Comment: I apologize for not pasting the code. I have edited my post.

Comment: Never mind, can you also post `json` response from server or rendered `html` will be fine too.. Also when you add comment if you want to notify user begin with `@` and username, as in my case @GuruprasadRao to notify me.. Other wise we wouldnt be knowing about your comment or update..

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao:
{"sEcho":"1","iTotalRecords":4,"iTotalDisplayRecords":4,"aaData":[["1","22EF581100","Shampoo","0090456890","9.80","4.50","5","2000018590-01","13.33","","JOHNSON","Boston","Houston","Texas"],["2","22EF581100","Toothpaste","0090456890","5.50","3.50","5","2000018590-01","15.66","","Merk","Dallas","Los Angeles","California"],["3","22EF581100","Hair Gel","0090456890","5.66","2.50","5","2000018590-01","14.67","","Sun","Dallas","San Antonio","Texas"],["4","22EF581100","Hair Cream","0090456890","3.33","3.89","5","2000018590-01","12.56","","JOHNSON","Dallas","Dallas","Texas"]]}

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao: The post is edited now with full information. Please help me out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is one level of setting on how you can make editable rows based on the `radio button` selected

```
//Add on change event to radio button and capture its value
$("input[name=filter]").on('change', function() {
    $("table tbody tr").each(function() {
        var val = $(this).find('td input[type="text"]').val();
        $(this).find('td input[type="text"]').closest('td').html(val)
    });
    //make any editable rows to non-editable by looping through each of them
    makeEditable(this.value);//call the function and pass the value of selected radio.
})

//this method assumes that the value of radio button and thead column are same and case sensitive
function makeEditable(val) {
    var FTheadIndex = $('#tblBadFormat thead th:contains(' + val + ')').index();
   //FTheadIndex will contain the index of column which matches the value of selected radio from first table
    var STheadIndex = $("#tblNotInBad thead th:contains(" + val + ")").index();
   //STheadIndex will contain the index of column which matches the value of selected radio from second table

    //loop through each row from first table and find the column index equivalent to Selected column
    $.each($('#tblBadFormat tbody tr'), function() {
        var td = $(this).find('td:eq(' + FTheadIndex + ')');
        td.html('<input type="text" value="' + td.text() + '"/>')
        //replace its html with input text and set its value to present value for that row
    })
    //same as above for 2nd table.        
    $.each($('#tblNotInBad tbody tr'), function() {
        var td = $(this).find('td:eq(' + STheadIndex + ')');
        td.html('<input type="text" value="' + td.text() + '"/>')
    })
}
```

## [`Here is the DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/tkjq3zfr/)

Now to save this to Database, you've to first decide on what event you want to save this to `DB`. On focus out from `textbox` or on click of any button. If you let me know I can suggest you accordingly.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :) Do make a note of restrictions which I mentioned in code comments..

Comment: Ok will do that.. Thanks!